# Sierra Leone fluorescent tube antenna

Tags: antenna

Young men in Sierra Leone are making antennas from fluorescent tubes mounted on wooden frames with wire leads.

How would the gain from these devices compare with that of more conventional devices that they replace? Where can I read about how they work?

Comment: I'll book a flight. http://phys.org/news/2015-06-wi-fi-antenna-wireless-coverage.html. Yes plasma negative resistance can be used to amplify RF at a tuned resonance. The tube intensity suggests it exceeds the IEEE specifications for a 1W WiFi router although...not to mention violate FCC and EU regulations for unlicensed WiFi. and perhaps fry your eyes in close range (caterogenic)

Comment: Big help, guys. So, for the unwashed, this is just silly? I actually saw this mentioned at http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-37550324.

Comment: Just for reference FCC cover the USA and EU regulations cover the European Economic Area... Sierra Leone is in West Africa and the standards are not the same!

Comment: Not silly.  The article Tony Stewart linked to mentions a possible use for it (wifi in offices with lots of fluorescent tubes.)  Other than that, its a really cool experiment.  For normal home use, not so much.  A regular commercially available antenna would be much more reasonable (easy setup and use.)

Comment: However, the one picture I can find of such a Sierra Leone antenna doesn't show the tubes being powered, so I wouldn't think they are using the technique in the article that Tony Stewart linked.  More likely it is working like a dipole using the two wires that run to the ends of the tubes.  Lord only knows what the impedance or the frequency response is like.

Comment: @JRE: I agree that it's unlikely that the tubes are powered since the materials cost only a few dollars/pounds. When I realised how foolish my question was and started to think about it (in the shower) the thought that they're making dipoles suddenly struck me. Most peculiar.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: I thought you were pulling my leg.

Comment: No in fact plasma lamps are the defacto antenna for the 60GHz? future Wifi Bands. THe RF does not light up the tube, but it also works whether the light is on or not due to the localized ionization or glow when off.  this was invented almost a hundred years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You realize, of course, that it's the horizontal wires running along the tube that functions as the antenna — the fluorescent tube itself contributes nothing to the process, other than providing a "standard length" for the assembly.

As for the article that Tony found, it's a bit like [catching birds by putting salt on their tails](http://farmersalmanac.com/home-garden/2009/02/23/salting-a-birds-tail-fact-or-folklore/). If you have to run a coax cable to every fixture anyway, you might as well install an ordinary cheap WiFi antenna, which will work regardless of whether the light is on or off.

Comment: I didn't realise that until hours after I put the question! They should keep people like me off this site.

Comment: The incremental negative resistance of gas ionization has a lot of similarities  with the negative resistance of telephony amplifiers.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: Radio waves of 2.4 GHz or even 5.0 GHz do not have anywhere near enough energy to ionize anything. Ionization requires photons of much higher energy, with wavelengths shorter than that of visible light.

Comment: e.g. e.g. http://calhoun.nps.edu/bitstream/handle/10945/778/NPS-CRC-03-001.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y